# Install old version NPM on Mac OS (12.0)

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, nvm, libstdc++

I try to install **nodejs 8.17** (it's requirement for my work-project) on **MacOS 12.0**.

I use NVM for it. But I got following error:

> clang: warning: include path for libstdc++ headers not found; pass '-stdlib=libc++' on the command line to use the libc++ standard library instead [-Wstdlibcxx-not-found]

How can I avoid this issue (without VM and docker)? I did't find way for installing **libstdc++**.